# How to put C++ console application to system tray notification?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console-application, system-tray

I tried putting window application on the system tray and it works fine. When I tried to modify it and use the console application instead it doesn't work. I've searched on the world wide web and found an answer stating that it will work if you can get the handle of the console. I'm new in winapi does anyone can help me? Here's my code so far.

```
#define ID_TRAY_APP_ICON    1001
#define ID_TRAY_EXIT        1002
#define WM_SYSICON          (WM_USER + 1)
#define IDI_ICON1                       101


/*variables*/

UINT WM_TASKBAR = 0;
HWND Hwnd;
HMENU Hmenu;
NOTIFYICONDATA notifyIconData;


LPCWSTR szClassName = L"System Tray.";

const char* szTIP = "Decryptdcode!";



/*procedures  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void minimize();
void restore();
void InitNotifyIconData();


//int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)
 int main(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow = 0)
{

/*HWND Hwnd = GetConsoleHwnd();
std::cout << GetConsoleWindow() << std::endl;*/

HWND Hwnd2 = GetConsoleWindow();
HWND NewWindow;
std::cout << "Console Title = " << Hwnd << std::endl;

TCHAR currentTitle[512];
TCHAR newCurrentTitle[512];
GetConsoleTitle(currentTitle, sizeof(currentTitle) / sizeof(TCHAR));
std::cout << "Previous Title = " << currentTitle << std::endl;

SetConsoleTitle(_T("New Console Window Title"));

Sleep(40);

//Hwnd2 = FindWindow(NULL, currentTitle);

GetConsoleTitle(newCurrentTitle, sizeof(newCurrentTitle) / sizeof(TCHAR));
std::cout << "Previous Title = " << newCurrentTitle << std::endl;

Hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();


/* This is the handle for our window */
MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */
WM_TASKBAR = RegisterWindowMessageA("TaskbarCreated");

/* The Window structure */
wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
wincl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);



/* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255)));

/* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */

if (!RegisterClassEx(&wincl))
    return 0;

/* The class is registered, let's create the program*/


//    Hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
//  0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
//  szClassName,         /* Classname */
//  szClassName,       /* Title Text */
//  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
//  CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
//  CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */   
//  200,                 /* The programs width */   
//  200,                 /* and height in pixels */ 
//  HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
//  NULL,                /* No menu */
//  hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
//  NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
//);

/*Initialize the NOTIFYICONDATA structure only once*/

InitNotifyIconData();

/* Make the window visible on the screen */
ShowWindow(Hwnd, nCmdShow);
//ShowWindow(Hwnd, SW_RESTORE);

/* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
while (GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
    TranslateMessage(&messages);

    /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
    DispatchMessage(&messages);

}
return messages.wParam;
}

/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
if (message == WM_TASKBAR && !IsWindowVisible(Hwnd))
{
    minimize();
    return 0;

}

switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
{
case WM_ACTIVATE:

    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &notifyIconData);
    break;

case WM_CREATE:
    ShowWindow(Hwnd, SW_HIDE);

    Hmenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    AppendMenu(Hmenu, MF_STRING, ID_TRAY_EXIT, TEXT("Exit The Demo"));

    break;

case WM_SYSCOMMAND:

    /*In WM_SYSCOMMAND messages, the four low-order bits of the wParam parameter
    are used internally by the system. To obtain the correct result when testing the value of wParam,
    an application must combine the value 0xFFF0 with the wParam value by using the bitwise AND operator.*/

    switch (wParam & 0xFFF0)
    {

    case SC_MINIMIZE:

    case SC_CLOSE:
        minimize();
        return 0;
        break;
    }

    break;

    // Our user defined WM_SYSICON message.

case WM_SYSICON:
{
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case ID_TRAY_APP_ICON:
        SetForegroundWindow(Hwnd);
        break;
    }

    if (lParam == WM_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        restore();
    }

    else if (lParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
    {

        // Get current mouse position.                  
        POINT curPoint;
        GetCursorPos(&curPoint);
        SetForegroundWindow(Hwnd);

        // TrackPopupMenu blocks the app until TrackPopupMenu returns           
        UINT clicked = TrackPopupMenu(Hmenu, TPM_RETURNCMD | TPM_NONOTIFY, curPoint.x, curPoint.y, 0, hwnd, NULL);
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_NULL, 0, 0); // send benign message to window to make sure the menu goes away.

        if (clicked == ID_TRAY_EXIT)

        {

            // quit the application.

            Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &notifyIconData);

            PostQuitMessage(0);

        }

    }

}

break;

// intercept the hittest message..
case WM_NCHITTEST:
{
    UINT uHitTest = DefWindowProc(hwnd, WM_NCHITTEST, wParam, lParam);
    if (uHitTest == HTCLIENT)
        return HTCAPTION;
    else
        return uHitTest;
}

case WM_CLOSE:
    minimize();
    return 0;
    break;

case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
}
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);

}

void minimize()
{
// hide the main window
ShowWindow(Hwnd, SW_HIDE);
}

void restore()
{
 ShowWindow(Hwnd, SW_SHOW);
}


void InitNotifyIconData()
{
memset(&notifyIconData, 0, sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA));
notifyIconData.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
notifyIconData.hWnd = Hwnd;
notifyIconData.uID = ID_TRAY_APP_ICON;
notifyIconData.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP;
notifyIconData.uCallbackMessage = WM_SYSICON; //Set up our invented Windows Message
notifyIconData.hIcon = (HICON)LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));

char output[256] = {};
//const WCHAR* wc = notifyIconData.szTip;
sprintf_s(output, "%ws", notifyIconData.szTip);
//strncpy(notifyIconData.szTip, szTIP, sizeof(szTIP));
strncpy_s(output, szTIP, sizeof(szTIP));
}
```

Comment: How exactly does your application run?  Do you want it to run as a long running application (hence, the systray icon) and have a console as a windows? Or do you expect the user to run it from the command line, and the systray just stays around until the command completes. Knowing this will generate the right answer...  In other words, it's very unusual for a console app to be using a systray icon....

Comment: You are setting console window handle for notify icon struct. `WindowProcedure` will only be called for windows belonging to the window class you registered, console window is not one of them. So tray notifications won't work.

Comment: @selbie I want my console application to run in the system tray until the user exit it(end process). Even I've clicked the close button the console window must stay still in the system tray and when I'm going to double-click it from the system tray the console application will gonna show.

Comment: @VTT Yeah. I think you're right. The code doesn't treat console application as a window class. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Create a hidden window to handle the messages.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Interesting. Can you give me a brief overview in order to run my console program on the systray successfully? :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think I need to read more posts about winapi inorder to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

`GetConsoleWindow()` is not your window, it belongs to a different process that might outlive your console application. On <= Vista `GetConsoleWindow` returns a system window you can't even subclass so there is no way to receive the tray icon messages.

Uncomment the code where you create your own window and use that HWND when you call `Shell_NotifyIcon`.

If you want your icon to outlive the console window then you should create a GUI application instead. It can call `AllocConsole` when you need a console window.

Comment: I'll try to implement this one. :)